# CSS оформление хлебных крошек

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать такую навигационную панель? ширина может увеличиваться смотря от названия категории
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуй, Как-то [так](https://ruseller.com/lessons/les1507/demo/index.html)

Comment: Тут linear-gradient мешает (

Comment: я бы сделал svg =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, #ff5f4d);
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 35px;
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #ff5f4d;
  right: -35px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 18px solid transparent;
  border-left: 23px solid white;
  right: -42px;
  top: -3px;
  z-index: 40;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Главная</a>
  <a href="">Каталог</a>
  <a href="">Очень длинное название</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Супер хороший метод)

Answer (score 4):

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  color: #fff;
  font: bold 12px verdana, sans-serif;
  background: #FAF8FB;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.breadcrumbs div {
  float: left;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #A82229, #EE3844);
  padding: 6px 16px 6px 26px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #FAF8FB;
}
.breadcrumbs div:first-child {
  background: #DAD8D9;
  color: #333;
}
.breadcrumbs span {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.breadcrumbs div:after {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: -10px;
  top: 4px;
  background: #EA3743;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 0 #FAF8FB
}
.breadcrumbs div:first-child:after {
  background: #DAD8D9;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <div>Главная</div>
  <div>Каталог товаров</div>
  <div>Компьютеры</div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: неплохо, но вот поворот дает красную обводку...

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, согласен, но это можно поиграться с цветами, легко решаемо

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, убрал обводку

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант с использованием `svg` и `css` `border-image` такой вариант более гибок и не имеет некоторых дефектов в некоторых ситуациях, вроде не сплошного бэкграунда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
breadcrumbs a {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px; 
    padding: 0 10px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: default;
    color: snow;
 
    margin-right: -11px;
    border-left: 10px solid white;
    border-right: 10px solid white;
    border-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,\
      <svg width='130px' height='30px' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>\
        <defs><linearGradient id='grad'>\
          <stop offset='0%' stop-color='%23aa2222'></stop>\
          <stop offset='100%' stop-color='red'></stop>\
        </linearGradient></defs>\
        <path d='M1,1 h118 l10,14 l-10,14 h-118 l10,-14 z' fill='url(%23grad)'/>\
      </svg>");
    border-image-slice: 0 11 0 11 fill;
}

breadcrumbs a.active {
    border-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,\
      <svg width='30px' height='30px' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>\
        <path d='M1,1 h18 l10,14 l-10,14 h-18 l10,-14 z' fill='lightgray'/>\
      </svg>"); 
    border-image-slice: 0 11 0 11 fill;
    color: black;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, wheat, white) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<breadcrumbs>
  <a class="active">Главная</a>
  <a>Каталог товаров</a>
  <a>Компьютеры</a>
</breadcrumbs>
```